# multiple linear regression analysis with continuous and categorical data result interpretation

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, predictor

I have data from gene expression arrays and I have clinical data associated with the samples used. I am using gene expression (discrete), age at diagnosis (discrete) and ethnicity (categorical) to build a regression model. I'd like to predict gene expression by age at diagnosis and ethnicity so the model would be something like:

$$y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + \epsilon$$

in R it looks something like:

```
y <- as.numeric(gene_expression_myFavoriteGenes)
age <- age_diagnosis 
ethnicity <- ethnicity 
l <- lm(y ~ age + ethnicity)
```

now...when I look at the coefficients I get something like:

```
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      -0.442785   0.151175  -2.929 0.008299 ** 
age_diagnosis    -0.005616   0.002422  -2.319 0.031090 *  
Caucasian        -0.910633   0.115870  -7.859 1.53e-07 ***
Hispanic         -0.801088   0.125429  -6.387 3.13e-06 ***
Honduran         -0.682405   0.210694  -3.239 0.004114 ** 
Peurto Rican     -0.679251   0.209620  -3.240 0.004100 ** 
South Asian      -1.237134   0.213569  -5.793 1.14e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1815 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7795,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7023 
F-statistic:  10.1 on 7 and 20 DF,  p-value: 2.21e-05
```

I'm a lil confused on how to interpret the data.
I first built the model without correcting for ethnicity, nothing was significant. 
then I added ethnicity, checked with `anova(fist_lm, second_lm)` and the difference is significant.

so now I have all ethnicity associated with a significant p-value and and adjusted R^2 of 0.7 ...so, my questions, sorry if they sound silly, are:

- in this specific case, can age + ANY ethnicity significantly predict expression of myFavoriteGene?
- models with other genes only have one or two significant ethnicity, does that mean that those are the only ones that can reliably predict expression of myFavoriteGene?

------- edit ---------

here an example of how my data look:

```
> data[1:10,1:6]
           skin.AA_2  skin.AA_3  skin.AA_4  skin.AA_5  skin.AA_6   skin.AA_7
100_g_at   5.5526731  4.7001569  5.3724104  5.3700587  5.7571421  5.76974711
1000_at    7.7757596  5.4761710  7.3896019  5.5514442  8.2559761  7.14107706
1001_at    1.4554496  0.3315354  1.3311387  1.4979105  2.0579317  1.50734217
1002_f_at -0.4427732 -0.7381431 -0.3714425 -0.3159300 -0.2270056  0.31245288
1003_s_at  1.7908548  1.2590320  1.4839795  1.6727171  1.8550568  1.99870500
1004_at    1.8082815  0.9940647  1.4085169  1.8658939  1.9275267  2.25192977
1005_at    3.1792907 10.2456153  6.1170771  9.9058017  8.3695269  5.02225258
1006_at   -0.3059731 -0.8761517 -0.7151807 -0.4620902 -0.5923052  0.02495093
1007_s_at  9.9911387 10.2839949 10.1105075  9.9944011 10.3866696 10.31211765
1008_f_at  7.9190579  4.5957139  4.0043624  4.6297893  4.2067368  7.62499810

> clinicalData[1:10,1:5]  
patient_ID        ethnicity age_diagnosis age colname_data_matrix_SB
1      AA1005 African American            39  47              skin.AA_1
2      AA1007        Caucasian            32  50              skin.AA_3
3      AA1008        Caucasian            50  50              skin.AA_4
4      AA1009        Caucasian            18  68              skin.AA_5
5      AA1010        Caucasian            31  40              skin.AA_6
6      AA1015        Caucasian            41  43                       
7      AA3001         Hispanic            49  49              skin.AA_7
8      AA3006         Hispanic            48  51              skin.AA_8
9      AA3007         Hispanic            51  51              skin.AA_9
10     AA3008         Hispanic            49  50             skin.AA_10
```

Comment: Can you provide the head command of your data, or do a str? It just sounds like more of a logit model...

Comment: @AntoniParellada I edited the txt so now it contains a head of the gene data and the clinical data. do you think a generalized linear model would be more appropriate then? thanks!

Comment: I don't have a good handle of your data. Perhaps a str would have done the trick; or somebody with more experience will answer your question.

Comment: @AntoniParellada the results from `str(data)` is `'data.frame': 12625 obs. of  60 variables:` they are all `num`, not sure if you want me to paste the whole table. for the `str(clinicalData)` i get `chr [1:78, 1:8] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:8] "disease" "patient_ID" "ethnicity" "age_diagnosis" ...` where `AA` is the abbreviation for a disease name (Alopecia Areata). hopefully this helps.